how to add quill in angular 17
I am trying to add "ngx-quill": "^25.3.2","quill": "^2.0.1" for a rich text editor. but not able to use it. please suggest to me the best way to use the quill.
The quill css is not working properly. I tried to solve it but it didn't work
